# How do you get the number of masked rows in a numpy masked array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a numpy array that contains a number of numpy arrays where some of them have masked values that looks like the one below:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [-- -- --]
 [7 8 9]]
```

What is the most efficient way to get the number of masked numpy arrays (meaning something like [-- -- --]) in the bigger numpy array (in this case it would be 1).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[Masked arrays have a `.mask` attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#accessing-the-mask) consisting of a boolean array that is `True` wherever a value is masked. If you want to know how many rows contained *at least one* masked value, you could use:

```
x.mask.any(axis=1).sum()
```

where `x` is your masked array. If you are only interested in rows where *all* of the values are masked, you could use:

```
x.mask.all(axis=1).sum()
```

Obviously in your example these would both give a result of 1.